# RANK IF formula on Google Sheets with SUM

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, rank, sumifs

I am trying to create a ranking of summed numbers out of a database.
The Database has a list of individual offices of companies  in certain countries (numbered 1-10). In some cases, the same company is in multiple countries.
Countries are listed in Column A; Companies are in column B; Offices are in column C.

Each individual office has a score. Office scores are in column D of the database.

I would like to create a rank of companies based on the company's total score per country. The company's total score per country is the sum of scores of all offices of the same company in the same country.

In order to build such a ranking one would have to:

1 - Get the company's total score per country. I have done this using a `SUMIFS` function. This is the function I've used to calculate this score: `=SUMIFS($D$2:$D, $A$2:$A, $A2, $B$2:$B, $B2)`. This is calculated in column E of the database.

2- Rank it against the list of other companies' total score per country only for those companies that are in the same country.

I am having trouble defining the range for the `RANK` and have learnt that this is not possible to do using a function like this. The range against which to rank the value calculated on step 1 needs to be a conditional sum as well - the sum of all scores in the country of the office we are ranking. How can this be done?

After doing some research, I have tried solutions involving `SUMPRODUCT` and `COUNTIFS` but have failed to achieved the desired result. How can I do this?

I have created a [sample shee](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C0vDY4FKcJqbkGtDWb-6P-pq_g0WuQOHxa7MrBhfw1k/edit?usp=sharing)t here that might help to understand the problem [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C0vDY4FKcJqbkGtDWb-6P-pq_g0WuQOHxa7MrBhfw1k/edit?usp=sharing).

Thank you

Comment: If I understand well, you want to have another column that only contains a number and is 1 for the best company of a country, 2 for the second best, etc?

Comment: That's exactly it. 1 for the company with best score in country, 2 for the company with second best score in the country, etc. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to rank them, you 1st have to find and sort all the values for the current country.
Like @|'-'|, I used a query:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$E;"select E WHERE A="&A2&" ORDER BY E DESC")
```

Since the same number can apear twice, you want to add a `UNIQUE` around that. Be carefull, if 2 companies have the same score, they'll have the same rank.

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY($A$2:$E;"select E WHERE A="&A2&" ORDER BY E DESC"))
```

This will return the range, sorted from the greatest to the least. Now you simply have to get the index of your current score with the match function.

```
=MATCH(E2;UNIQUE(QUERY($A$2:$E;"select E WHERE A="&A2&" ORDER BY E DESC"));0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your answer is great and very clear. However, I am having some trouble implementing it. In the sample sheet, I have used numbers to represent countries. In that case, the last formula you wrote works perfectly. However, whenever I use it with specific country names, the query doesn't seem to work. It doesn't recognize the country names and returns an error. It only works if I replace `A="&A2&"` for `A='Algeria'`, for example. Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: I've worked it out. The problem was that the cell referencing was not being done properly. It should be `A=' "&A2&" '` instead. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
=query(A:D,"Select A,B,sum(D) group by A,B order by A,sum(D) desc")
```

This doesn't RANK,but  SORTs the SUM in the descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Rank the selection against a filtered range.  Example:

=Rank(C2,Filter(C$2:$C$71,F$2:$F$71=F2),1)

This would rank the value in c2 only if the values in f2:f72 are equal to the value in f2 (this rankes the lowest values with the lowest rank